# The necessity of feature scaling before fitting a classifier in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I used to believe that `scikit-learn`'s [Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) classifier (as well as [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)) automatically standardizes my data before training. The reason I used to believe it is because of the regularization parameter `C` that is passed to the `LogisticRegression` constructor: Applying regularization (as I understand it) doesn't make sense without feature scaling. For regularization to work properly, all the features should be on comparable scales. Therefore, I used to assume that when calling the `LogisticRegression.fit(X)` on training data `X`, the `fit` method first performs feature scaling and then starts training. In order to test my assumption I've decided to manually scale the features of `X` as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X_std = scaler.transform(X)
```

Then I've initialized a `LogisticRegression` object with a regularization parameter `C`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
log_reg = LogisticRegression(C=10.0, random_state=0)
```

I've found out that training the model on `X` is not equivalent to training the model on `X_std`. That is to say, the model produced by

```
log_reg.fit(X_std, y)
```

is not similar to the model produced by

```
log_reg.fit(X, y)
```

Does that mean that `scikit-learn` doesn't standardize the features before training? Or maybe it does scale but by applying a different procedure? If `scikit-learn` doesn't perform feature scaling, how is it consistent with requiring the regularization parameter `C`? Should I manually standardize my data every time before fitting the model in order for regularization to make sense?

Comment: You're not setting the `random_state` param in both cases, try passing `random_state=0` for `LogisticRegression` ctor, by default it's `None` so any variance you see maybe due to this, see the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Comment: @EdChum: Good point, thanks. But I actually have passed the `random_state=0` parameter when testing the above. I've forgotten to state that in my question so I'm editing the question now.

Answer (score 0):

From the following note in: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

I'd assume that you need to preprocess the data yourself (e.g. with a scaler from sklearn.preprocessing.)

solver : {‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’}

Algorithm to use in the optimization problem.
For small datasets, ‘liblinear’ is a good choice, whereas ‘sag’ is faster for large ones.

For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’ and ‘lbfgs’ handle multinomial loss; ‘sag’ and ‘liblinear’ are limited to one-versus-rest schemes.

‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’ and ‘sag’ only handle L2 penalty.

**Note that ‘sag’ fast convergence is only guaranteed on features with approximately the same scale. You can preprocess the data with a scaler from sklearn.preprocessing.**